# display a list differently Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

hey i was wandering if it was possible to show a list:

```
["one", "two", "three"]
```

to be shown as

```
"one", "two", "three"
```

need it done for a file

thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with `intercalate` from `Data.List`

```
 showList :: Show a => [a] -> String
 showList = intercalate ", " . map show
```

The `map show` converts each element to it's string representation with quotes (and any internal quotes properly escaped), while `intercalate ", "` inserts commas and spaces between the pieces and glues them together.

Comment: @Tom: That's just how the interpreter shows the resulting string to you. Try using `putStrLn (showList ["one", "two", "three"])` to print it instead. For comparison, see the difference between just typing in `"hello"` and `putStrLn "hello"`.

Comment: @nanothief: The use of `show` to produce the inner quotes is intended here. The confusion arises because the interpreter calls `show` _again_ on the result to display it.

Comment: Yes you are right, I didn't read his requirements closely enough. It was my comments that were wrong :S (I've deleted them since they will do nothing but confuse).