# Removing additional quotes from strings in Haskell

Tags: string, list, file, haskell, io

hey on my file i have a line like this

```
"Dave", "Zoe", "Amy", "Bill", "Ian", "Kevin", "Emma", "Sam", "Megan"
```

when handling  it and hgetline to change it to a string it causes it to go to

```
"\"Dave\", \"Zoe\", \"Amy\", \"Bill\", \"Ian\", \"Kevin\", \"Emma\", \"Sam\", \"Megan\""
```

I obviously cant do [putStr String] cause putStr is IO()

is there a way of getting rid of the \ or something.

thanks

Comment: Similar to your earlier question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829985/display-a-list-differently-haskell -- you'll post-process the results of `show` to strip out, or add, the characters you want

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683210/showing-a-haskell-list-of-tuples-with-custom-syntax

Comment: You should post code to ensure people understand your problem.  Right now my thinking is you just saw the result of `show` on something `:: [String]` and are concerned about the escaped characters; in this case the `\\`'s aren't actually part of the string, just the GHCi rendering of the string.  Write a program that performs your action and outputs the result to a file or the terminal.  If that doesn't behave properly _then_ come back here with a question and some code that exhibits the issue.

Comment: well with the above it will cause all the '\' to be put onto the file when I write over it at the end. dont want that to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that you read lines from a file that contain:

```
"Dave", "Zoe", "Amy", "Bill", "Ian", "Kevin", "Emma", "Sam", "Megan"
```

When that is read in via, e.g. `readFile` or `getLine`, those quotes will be in your string too.

You can then go ahead and process the string however you want. For example, by splitting it on whitespace, and removing additional quote characters:

```
> map (filter (/='"')) (words s)
["Dave,","Zoe,","Amy,","Bill,","Ian,","Kevin,","Emma,","Sam,","Megan"]
```

See further answers on list processing f[or more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874600/cutting-a-string-into-a-list-in-haskell).

Comment: what if thers 2 words like "tom Baker", "Dave Bla"

Answer (score 1):

If those strings were printed with `show`, which they probably were, considering your previous question, try reading them with `read`. The `read` function is the opposite of `show` and undoes its effect, that is removes the quotes and un-escapes the escaped characters.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough. It seems you don't have any problem yet. :D
The string you presented is obviously an output from ghci, and the real string does not contain any slashes. However, I still assume you want to read the individual names in your program, for which you'd need `read`. To use it, you'd have to split your string on commas first. However, if any of the names themselves contain a comma this becomes non-trivial.

The easiest solution I see for this is to prepend "[", append "]", and let the `read` function handle everything.
Like this:

```
readList :: String -> [String]
readList str = read ("[" ++ str ++ "]")
```

That is assuming you have printed them with `showList` from the [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5829985/display-a-list-differently-haskell)